# Cannot find module 'actions-on-google'

Tags: actions-on-google

I was going through google's tutorial for their action, while trying to make some modifications to suit what I was trying to do. When I run the terminal command 'firebase deploy', after a bit of processing my terminal will say: "Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'actions-on-google'. Try running npm-install in your functions directory before deploying.

I have run npm-install in the functions directory, but have had no luck in getting this to work.

Here is the top bit of code in my index.js file:

```
'use strict';

process.env.DEBUG = 'actions-on-google:*';
const {DialogflowApp} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.echoNumber = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const app = new DialogflowApp({request: req, response: res});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have a package.json file in that directory. It should have a dependencies section. And in that section there should be a line for every package that you require().

In particular

"actions-on-google": "^1.8.0",

Comment: Solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, i felt `npm i -S actions-on-google` also worked

Answer (score 2):

When this happened to me it was because I was trying to run the command from the base directory instead of the functions directory.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below command in your Project/functions directory before deploy

npm install firebase-admin@5.5.0

npm install

It will work properly

Answer (score 0):

After exhausting the other answers, this worked for me

1. Delete the `functions/node_modules folder`
2. Using command prompt run `npm install` on the functions folder

My best guess is a corrupted `functions/node_modules/actions-on-google` folder

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the commands following in sequence:

1. `npm install action on google`
2. `npm install`

This worked for me might be useful for you too.